# Domain name mapping and relative URLs

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have a domain name that I have mapped to an EC2 elastic IP.  When I go to the domain name, it does the right thing.  However, when I follow relative URLs, it does not -- it simply goes to the same domain name (with no parameters appended).

For example, suppose I have foo.com mapped to 1.2.3.4

1) When I go to foo.com, it indeed goes to 1.2.3.4

2) One of the links on foo.com is to "details.php?a=1", so following that link should take one to "foo.com/details.php?a=1", but instead it takes them to "foo.com" (but the parameters seem to be passed, b/c the right thing happens)

3) When I mouse over the URL to "details.php?a=1", it shows that it is pointing to "1.2.3.4/details.php?a=1" (even this confuses me)

I have developed the app using only relative URLs, in part to avoid having a problem running it in different environments.  Might this be a registrar setting or am I doing something basic wrong here?  I can solve the problem by hardcoding foo.com into the URLs, but then I lose the elegance of the relative URLs.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: How did you map it to the elastic IP, exactly?  Right click that link and open in a new window and see what happens.  This sounds like some kind of stealth/frames-based Iinstead of DNS-based setup.

Comment: I did this and it goes to 1.2.3.4/details.php?a=1 which was expected given the mouse-over results in (3) above.  However, I don't know why a relative URL causes the original IP address to be inserted when the domain name is mapped to that IP address (and my location bar is currently at the domain name).  Very strange.